# Why isn't the state root checked on the client side?

Tags: runtime, runtime-api

Substrate requires that every header has a state root. (See [Trait `Header`](https://crates.parity.io/sp_runtime/traits/trait.Header.html).)

When the runtime executes a block authored by a peer, it is assumed that the runtime will check the state root from the header against the state that it has calculated itself. For example, FRAME does the [state root check in FRAME executive](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/executive/src/lib.rs#L476-L479).

Question: Why is it the runtime's job to do this check, when virtually every runtime will have to do it? Why isn't this check done on the client side so the runtime developer has no chance to forget?